# Why should we interpret a high order interaction (e.g. > 3-way) by only conditioning on 1 of the factors?

Tags: anova, interaction, interpretation

lets consider now we have conducted a 3-way anova and found a significant 3-way interaction effect A:B:C. As far as I am reading from textbooks/this website, the general suggestion is that we should choose to condition on 1 of the variables and then conduct post-hoc 2-way, 1-way and pairwise comparisons if necessary.

My question is, why should we only choose 1 direction and only interpret according to that direction?

For example, I could condition on A, and observed sig B:C interaction and go on to do post-hoc and interpret it.

At the same time, I could condition on B, and observed sig A:C interaction and so on.

The above example is a simplified case of my own analysis, which I indeed observed sig. 2-way interaction between the other 2 factors when I condition on A or B. However, my colleague suggests that I should only choose 1 path, and some textbooks I read suggest the same as well.